# HTML form with array of maps

Tags: html, arrays, forms, elixir

say I want to work with a array where the values are maps.

IE

```
[ %{ "foo" => "bar"}, %{ "foo" => "baz"} ]
```

I can get this to work with.

```
 <input name = "post[list][][foo]" value = "bar">
 <input name = "post[list][][foo]" value = "baz">
```

Ok so that works but what if I want to add more keys to one of the maps or both?

This is where things fall apart for me.

```
<input name = "post[list][][email]" value = "1@aol.com">
<input name = "post[list][][primary]" value = "false">

<input name = "post[list][][email]" value = "2@aol.com">
<input name = "post[list][][primary]" value = "true">
```

I end up with an array of 4 items like so.

```
[%{"email" => "1@aol.com"}, %{"primary" => "false"}, %{"email" => "2@aol.com"}, %{"primary" => "true"}]
```

When what I really wanted was an array of two items like so.

```
[%{"email" => "1@aol.com", "primary" => "false"}, %{"email" => "2@aol.com", "primary" => "true"}]
```

Notice that each maps has two keys `email`, and `primary` as the desired map. IE `%{"email" => "1@aol.com", "primary" => "false"}` as opose to what I ended up with which was an array of 4 maps each with one key.

Now I know this has to do with the way I named my inputs. Can anyone here help me?

FYI the context of this array and map is from Elixir.

Comment: I had a similar question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628425/extracting-params-from-a-form-with-deeply-nested-arrays-of-values and I guess there is no way to handle it easily, looks like adding indexes and then itirating through them is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you have index when iterating to render inputs.

You can render inputs like this with index.

```
<input name = "post[list][0][email]" value = "1@aol.com">
<input name = "post[list][0][primary]" value = "false">

<input name = "post[list][1][email]" value = "2@aol.com">
<input name = "post[list][1][primary]" value = "true">
```

Comment: The end result is a single map where the keys are the index. 

IE

`%{"1" => %{"bar" => "1", "foo" => "1"}, "2" => %{"bar" => "1", "foo" => "1"}}`

the point of [] was I wanted to have the parent be an array

Comment: @PolygonPusher this looks like the way to go. You'll have to convert it manually because your original form is ambigous -- it can either mean what Plug currently returns or what you want. Both are valid decodes of the form with those names.

Comment: While I agree this is the best work around, I want to keep this open as a opportunity for anyone to try and address the root question. That is a single array with many multi valued associative arrays